# How to use Controllers from one class library to another class library? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, controller, class-library

I want to make a project which will contain multiple class libraries (like 2-3 different ones). So I want to know is it possible for me to use controllers from one class library to another class library in ASP.NET?

Comment: That is definetly possible. Just add the class library as a reference where you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. You can write your controllers to a class library project and use them in different web projects. But I'm not sure this is the desired architecture. 
Make sure your class library has asp.net-mvc references like System.Web, System.Web.Mvc

Comment: Thanks, I will do more research